# シェルスクリプトでnode.jsがすでにインストール済みかチェックするには？

Tags: macos, node.js, shellscript

シェルスクリプトを始めたばかりなのですが、
件名の処理をどのようにしたら良いかわからず質問しました。

macにてシェルスクリプトを使って、Node.jsが入っていなければ、
Node.jsをダウンロードするという処理を書きたいのですが
入っていればと言うのをどのように書けば良いかわかりません。

Node.jsのダウンロードは、
下記のコマンドで実現できました。

```
curl -O https://nodejs.org/dist/v0.12.5/node-v0.12.5.pkg
```

処理としては下記のようになるはずです。

```
#!/bin/sh
if アプリが存在しない then
    curl -O https://nodejs.org/dist/v0.12.5/node-v0.12.5.pkg
fi
```

MacOSX:10.10.3

---

**■最終目的は下記の手順をシェルスクリプト化する事です。**

●Node.jsダウンロード

https://nodejs.org/download/

●ファイルサーバーとするフォルダを指定

1:フォルダ作成
　2:コマンドプロンプトから1:のフォルダへ移動
　例）cd /path/to/my/project
　3:コマンドプロンプトにて下記入力
　　npm install connect

●jsファイルを１のフォルダに作成

・ｊｓファイルの中身は下記ソース

```
var connect = require('connect'),
    serveStatic = require('serve-static');

var app = connect();
app.use(serveStatic(__dirname));
app.listen(5000);
```

・適当な名前で保存
　　仮にserver.jsとする。

●コマンドラインからサーバー実行
　1:コマンドプロンプトからjsファイルのフォルダへ移動
　2:下記コマンド入力
　　npm install serve-static

3:下記コマンド入力
　　node server.js

●下記htmlをindex.htmlという名前で作成し、
　jsファイルと同じフォルダに置く

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>hello connect</title>
</head>
<body>
hello connect
</body>
</html>
```

●ブラウザから下記URLをたたいてみると、
　hello connect　と表示される。
　表示されない時は、app.listen(5000)の
　ポート番号を変えてみて下さい。

http://127.0.0.1:5000/

---

06/26 追記

---

お力添えのおかげでとりあえず版ができました。

```
#!/bin/sh
node -v &> /dev/null
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
  curl -O https://nodejs.org/dist/v0.12.5/node-v0.12.5.pkg
fi

Current=`pwd`
NodePath=/NodeJs
CheckPath=$Current$NodePath
if [ ! -e $CheckPath ]; then
    mkdir -m 777 NodeJs
fi

cd $CheckPath
npm install connect

echo $CheckPath

JsFileName=LocalServer.js
if [ ! -e $JsFileName ]; then
    touch $JsFileName
    chmod 777 $JsFileName


    JsString="var connect = require('connect'),
        serveStatic = require('serve-static');
        var app = connect();
        app.use(serveStatic(__dirname));
        app.listen(5000);"

        echo "$JsString" > $JsFileName
fi

echo $JsFileName

HtmlFileName=Index.html
if [ ! -e $HtmlFileName ]; then
    touch $HtmlFileName
    chmod 777 $HtmlFileName

    HtmlString="<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="ja">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>hello connect</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    Make FileServer Success!
    </body>
    </html>"

    echo "$HtmlString" > $HtmlFileName
fi

echo $HtmlFileName

npm install serve-static

echo "Install End"

node $JsFileName
```

Comment: related : [stackoverflow : check if a program exists from a bash script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/592620/check-if-a-program-exists-from-a-bash-script/677212#677212)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

以下のような感じで、コマンドの存在確認用の関数を定義して、
それを利用して、下記のサンプルコードのようにして、
コマンドの存在確認を行ってみるといいのではないでしょうか？

```
function command_exists {
  command -v "$1" > /dev/null;
}

# node.jsがインストール済みかチェック
if ! command_exists node ; then
    curl -O https://nodejs.org/dist/v0.12.5/node-v0.12.5.pkg
fi
# npmが利用可能かチェック
if ! command_exists npm ; then
    #npmの手動インストール処理・・・
fi
```

また、シェルスクリプトを書き始めたばかりとのことでしたので、
私がシェルスクリプトを書き始めたときに、参考にしたサイトのURLを記載しておきます。

http://shellscript.sunone.me/

Comment: コマンド便利そうですね、世の中のエンジニアさんはどう組んでるのかがわからないので四苦八苦してます。とりあえず版を完成させることができました。mkdirを２回書いているのですが引数でパスを渡す形にまとめられないか調査しているのと。npk install ** の**がインストール済みかどうかチェックする方法を調査してます。

Comment: npmパッケージのインストールに関しては、記載されているとりあえず版の内容を見る限り、グローバルにはインストールしていないようようですので、以下のような感じで「node_modules」以下に
各パッケージのディレクトリが存在するかどうかで判定してはいかがでしょうか？

また、とりあえず版の内容を拝見すると、
コードをファイルに出力しているようですが、
以下のような感じでヒアドキュメントで記載した方が
メンテがしやすくなるのではないでしょうか？

http://qiita.com/take4s5i/items/e207cee4fb04385a9952

Comment: 各パッケージのフォルダがあるかを見ることで、インストールの有無を判定できました。　ヒアドキュメントは書いたコードを入力として渡せるという感じでしょうか？
ヒアドキュメントも一度実行してみます、ファイルを作成しなくてもコマンドに処理を渡せるのであれば非常にメンテコストが高いと思います。

Answer (score 3):

簡易的な方法として、`node -v`の実行に成功するかチェックするというのはどうでしょうか。

```
node -v &> /dev/null
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
  # nodeがインストールされていない
fi
```

Comment: コマンドの意味の確認なのですが、node -v &> /dev/null はnode.jsのバージョン取得をバックグラウンドで実行し、その結果をゴミ箱(/dev/null)に出力という意味であってますでしょうか？